# Entanglement and cosmological eras

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, quantum-entanglement

I'm checking this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7834

- In the context of quantum cosmology, they assume that the universe evolves in an entangled state between the two epochs considered, i.e.$$\left|\Psi\right\rangle =\alpha\left|e_{a}\right\rangle _{1}\left|e_{b}\right\rangle _{2}+\beta\left|e_{b}\right\rangle _{1}\left|e_{a}\right\rangle _{2}\in\mathbb{C}^{2}\otimes\mathbb{C}^{2},$$ with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$.
- Taking the density operator associated with that state, from a point of view of quantum information theory they define the negativity (a test for entanglement) and evaluate it as $$\mathcal{N}\equiv2\sum_{k}\max\left(0,-\lambda_{k}\right)=2\alpha\beta>0.$$
  [This is just an absolute sum of the negative eigenvalues - recall that, for separable states, the partial transpose density operator has to be positive (i.e., has non-negative eigenvalues only); otherwise, the state represented is entangled] The last one is their eq. (13). After that, they say that $\mathcal{N}$ is constant throughout the universe evolution.
- Then, on the same page (in the next column) they write that this same function $\mathcal{N}$ depends on the redshift $z$, and of course is not constant - in fact they model it as in eq. (18), i.e. $$\mathcal{N}\left(z\left(r_{{\rm AH}}\right)\right)=1+\sigma\frac{{\rm d}r_{{\rm AH}}}{{\rm d}z}=1-\frac{\sigma\left(q+1\right)}{H\left(1+z\right)},$$ where $q\equiv \dot{H}/H^{2}-1$ is the deceleration parameter, $H$ is the Hubble parameter and $r_{{\rm AH}}$ is the apparent horizon of the FRW metric (the radius until where causality is preserved, see the paper and references therein for more).

**My big problem now:**

Am I wrong somewhere when I say that the normalisation coefficients $\alpha$, $\beta$ are constant, and shouldn't depend on the redshift $z$?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and not depend on external material as far as possible.  I think you should at least show the equations you mention (using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) ) and explain what the meaning of symbols is supposed to be.

Comment: Agreed, it would be great to put the equations into the post so that this is more clear without external context. But at the same time I think this will be a really good question for the site once you've done that.

Comment: @StephenG now it looks better! Thanks

Comment: @DavidZ hope now it looks better! Thanks

Comment: Yep that's great! (At least, it looks pretty good to me, although it's possible someone who actually specializes in this field might suggest including something else - but don't worry about that unless you get comments about it.)